# Block a website from accessing router?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Im programming in VB.NET and i dont know how to block a website from the router.
Something similar to a Patch Blocker or similar to Anon Proxy Server just i need to know how to do this in vb.net.

More info: The thing is that i have a ps3 and want it to block certain url from accessing my router.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?
What error messages did you receive?

Comment: I Haven't got any error message. i just want to know the code. as im have programmed in vb.net for around 4-7 months and it seems that i learn faster from looking at codes

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a .Net guy, but what I would do to keep my application from resolving a hostname, is simply check if the hostname is in a backlist, and don't pass it to the [Dns.Resolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.resolve%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method.

Notice I said within my application. You can't have a piece of software running on your machine prevent your PS3 from talking to the router with nothing else in place. You would have to turn your machine into a proxy or a router in order for it to block PS3 requests. What it would take to develop a proxy is out of scope for this question.

Having your router block access based, on IP, or to domains, would be a question for superuser or serverfault.